# multi homed Ubuntu sever with site to site vpn

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, linux-networking

I have a site to site vpn between the two network 192. 168.XXX.XXX (local) and 192.168.YYY.YYY (remote). I have Ubuntu box that is multi homed that is configured with 192.168.ZZZ.Z , gateway of 192.168.Z.1 and second address with 192.168.XXX.X. I am not able to get to 192.168.YYY.YYY network. Can this be accomplished? Do I need to setup static route on the ubutu box, if so I don’t know how? Any help would be appreciated. Note, I have no issues with vpn tunnel with single adapter just struggling with the multi-homed ubuntu box.

Comment: Please unmasq the X and Y. It looks like both networks share the same subnet and is confusing. Also provide us with _ifconfig -a_ (or _ip addr show_ if you lack net-tools) and _ip route show_ outputs.

Answer (score 0):

If your default gateway is ZZZ.1 then yes, you need to set a static route:

```
ip route add 192.168.YYY.YYY/YY via 192.168.XXX.X dev <the_nic_in_the_XXX_network>
```

The XXX.X should be the address of the box providing the VPN.

To make it permanent, you either have to add the static route in NetworkManager or in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file